# UDP, multithreading multiple clients?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, udp

I am working on an UDP client-server architecture where the server (naturally) can handle multiple clients. However I've ran into some problems. I currently have a "server" that accepts data from 1 socket, from IPAddress.Any. If it's an unknown IP, a new client instance is created and all the relevant data goes there.

Now here's the problems I've ran into. When trying to BeginReceiveFrom on both the "server" and the "clients", all the data is received twice, so naturally this isn't very helpful.
When restarting BeginReceiveFrom immediately after receiving data (but before parsing, checking etc) the data comes in a random order and sometimes data is missing. (I am connecting locally, so I doubt UDP will lose packets that frequent).

With a similar TCP architecture, you are able to run BeginReceiveFrom on every new client without problems. What's different here? How does the TCP stack handle distributing data to all of the connected clients?

How can I achieve something similar (or at the very least more threads than one)? Having to run one thread for (say 1.000) connections and having to parse/handle every single packet before a new one can be handled, is a massive performance drop.

Is it an idea to parse and "deliver" data to each of the clients and have that data be picked up & processed by 1 thread for every client?

I know people usually want to see some code to provide better help, but I don't think that will help much in this case (ask me if you think it will and I can provide some).

My current solution is, BeginReceiveFrom > EndReceiveFrom > Parse data > Check data > BeginReceiveFrom > etc.

UDP is by choice.

Comment: You could have one receiver thread and once it receives a packet, send it to another thread for processing, so it can be constantly receiving.

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, this was what came in my mind as well. But even after doing quite a bit of research, I'm not much further.
I was thinking about queueing received data directly as byte[] and processing it on different thread(s).
I understand that lock is fairly expensive in this scenario, what ways are there to make something like this happen? Also, can you advise me on the use of a threadpool for reading/processing the data from the buffer? How can I notify other threads that the queue has data available? Performance is a big issue for me. Thanks!